# Yii2 adding parameters to the model with a function

Tags: forms, activerecord, model, yii2

I have two types of data. Articles and article types. They are stored a postgres DB. Every article instance should have particular type. All articles have common properties like "name", "create_date" and so on that are in every article and fields that are specific for the specific type like "some_image", "ingredients", and so on for the type1 and "images" and "points" for type2.

The additional properties for the specific type are stored in a single json column in the db table.

When the url "some_path/articles/create/2" is opened a form for creating an article of type 2 is displayed

I have an Articles ActiveRecord model and ArticlesController.

My problem is that in the model I have only have the common properties. And the additional properties are always different.

I need a method in the model or in the controller with which I can add the additional properties with the proper rules and all (like the common properties in the model) and then in the view I can render all fields without difference.

Is there a way this to be done and how?

I read how this can be done with Javascript, but I want it to be dobe before page rendering, not after that

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help.

Use Scenario in your model

Model class has scenario function which you can inherit.

```
User Register Scenario - Required - username, password, email
User Login Scenario - Required - username, email


   public function scenarios() {
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios['login'] = ['name','password'];//Scenario Values Only Accepted
    return $scenarios;
   }
```

and you can use it as